# How to make corner radius in android

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I am trying to make a gridview which will have an image and text beneath it with corner radius effect. So far it seems not possible. Here is my Activity xml which is holding the gridview:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnWidth="140dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</ScrollView>
```

Here is the adapter xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:padding="2dp"
              android:layout_margin="20dp"
              android:background="@drawable/grid_corner_radius"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cat_life"
        android:layout_height="160dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/credit_textView"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Life"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="15dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And finally here is the corner radius magic code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
            <solid android:color="#C0C0C0"></solid>
            <corners android:radius="15dp"></corners>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

And the output is as under:

[image]

See the image's sharp rectangle edge is visible. What could be the possible solution?

Comment: You can use some [lib](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView) and set xml background also to textview.

Comment: By the way, you can save on a LinearLayout and an ImageView by setting the image as the TextView's top **compound drawable**. Great for enhancing performances (the flatter your layout hierarchy, the faster your Activity/Fragment).

Comment: Of course this `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`, as per the comment above, goes into the TextView declaration.

Answer (score 5):

You can encapsulate your adapter xml with CardView and set cornerRadius to it.It should work.

Add `compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'` to your app gradle file.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="2dp"
android:layout_margin="20dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_width="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/cat_life"
    android:layout_height="160dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/credit_textView"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Life"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="15dp"/>
      </LinearLayout>    
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Thanks @Dilpreet. Getting an error resource not found. Do I need to import anything?

Comment: Oh yes just add compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0' to your gradle file

Comment: Thanks for your effort @Dilpreet. Seems not working :(. I will update if I find any solution.

Answer (score 2):

try this code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/corners_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:background="@drawable/corners_image"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/credit_textView"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Life"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="@drawable/corners_text"
        android:textSize="15dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Use this style for layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryJob"/>
    <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
</shape>
```

Use this style for textview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorBlue"/>
    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp" android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"/>
</shape>
```

Use this style for imageview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryJob"/>
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="20dp" android:topRightRadius="20dp"/>
</shape>
```